# Appropriate response for excess KB submitted to REST API

Tags: api, rest, http-status-codes

We have a REST API which is rate-limted according to number of requests, but also amount of  KB submitted. If a client application exceeds their allowed quota of requests to an API endpoint we return a `429 Too Many Requests` response, as per [RFC6585](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585). But what is the appropriate response if a client exceeds the amount of KB allowed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
400 Bad Request
```

or:

```
403 Forbidden
```

or:

```
406 Not Acceptable
```

or:

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
```

Comment: Indeed we already use this for individual request which exceed our per-request size limit. Sorry for any lack of clarity, but my question was really about the situation in which a client's request might exceed their daily/weekly/monthly limit. Would 413 be appropriate for that?

Comment: Even `403` is a good response - since you can (and should) return the error message in the body

Comment: Thanks. I've seen 503, and was tempted to go with that, but it just seemed wrong, since it's really the client who's 'at fault'. 403 looks a good choice... Although I suppose 413 _is_ an appropriate response, given that at that point the request length _is_ too large...